# R: how to add points to multiple plots using apply?

Tags: r, plot, apply

I am trying to add points from columns in a data frame to multiple plots based on columns of another data frame, but I don't succeed in adding the points to the right graph/plot. See the example below (in reality I have more columns)

```
t <- seq(from = 0, to = 2*pi, by = pi/5)
mod <- cbind(sin(t),cos(t))
obs <- cbind(sin(t) + runif(11, -0.1, 0.1),cos(t) + runif (11, -0.1, 0.1))
```

I can make a graph with n plots depending on the number of columns in obs(ervations)

```
par(mfcol = c(ncol(obs), 1))
apply (obs, 2, function(x)
    plot(t, x, pch = 19))
```

but if I try to add the mod(elled) data to the right graphs using:

```
apply (mod, 2, function(x)
    points(t, x))
```

all the points are added to the lowest plot, which is obviously not what I want.

Any ideas how to make sure that the model output is plotted with the corresponding observations (i.e. (t, obs [,1]) and (t, mod[,1]) in the upper graph and (t, obs[,2]) and (t, mod[,2]) in the lower)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not simply the following?

```
par(mfcol=c(ncol(obs),1))
for(i in 1:ncol(obs)){
    plot(t,obs[,i],pch=19)
    points(t,mod[,i])
    }
```

Otherwise, to plot in a figure area that is not the current one, use `par` function with argument `mfg` (see`?par`).